# how to export variables from svelte:head to the html section?

Tags: html, ros, svelte-3, sveltekit

#### Rationale

I'm making a small website using svelte and sveltekit, and a library ([roslibjs](https://github.com/RobotWebTools/roslibjs)) that seems to be only usable within `<head>`.

It worked only in those 2 types of scenarios for me:

1. put everything in `<head>` and output to the console
2. import the library in `<head>`, but only by using `<script src='https link here'></script>`.
   Everything else goes into `onMount`, outside of `<head>`.

1 is not acceptable, and while 2 is a temporary fix, I really don't want to rely on external links. (the site might be used in an offline environment)

#### What I tried

1. Since if I have all the code relying on the library inside `<head>` it works just fine, I tried to do so. But so long I couldn't find a way to export variables from `<head>`.

Example:

```html
<svelte:head>
  <script>
    let a = 10
  </script>
</svelte:head>


<p>{a}</p>
```

This throws an error saying 'a' is not defined.

2. Change the import line to `<script src="node_modules/roslib/build/roslib.js"></script>`, directly from the `node_modules` folder.

While this works in `npm run dev`, it doesn't once after `npm run build`.

#### What I expect

To be able to use the library with svelte3, but by using it from npm, not an external link.

One way to tackle this might be to export variables from `<head>`, but I couldn't find a way to do so.

Comment: What about the [npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/roslib)?

Comment: @Corrl I did use the npm package with `import`, but it didn't work outside of <head> either.